# simple link_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

I have a page app/views/new/news.html.erb and I simply want to link to this page from within my layouts/application.html.erb. Can someone please help! I have been struggling with this all morning.

I have tried things like <%= link_to "News", ... But I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: Did you generate the view using scaffold or did you do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have it setup correctly you should have a plural for your controller (i.e. news instead of new) and the following should work:

```
<%= link_to 'News', :controller => "news", :action => :news %>
```

This is assuming you are using scaffold.

If are adding this folder and page manually: for dynamic page, you have to create an action in your controller. For static page, you have to put it in your public folder.

Answer (score 4):

You don't "link" to a view, you link to a controller which renders that view. Then, you'll need an entry in your routes.rb to wire up the url routing for that controller. If you have a controller named NewsController with a method called index and an entry in your routes.rb that looks like `resources :news` the following link_to should work: `link_to "News", news_path`.

In case it's not clear, the index method in your NewsController needs to have `render :news` in it.

Sounds like you may want to check out the guide on this topic: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can always run

```
rake routes > routes.txt
```

in your application directory, which will dump a list of all routes into a txt file. Choose path that leads to action and controller you want, and then supply it as a param for link_to method :)